# R: I have a function with an invisible return value, how can I vectorize it and not get a huge null output?

Tags: r, list, null, return, void

I have written a fairly simple function, that I believe returns nothing:

```
bar<-function(a,b)
{
  if(foo(a,b)){print(c(a,b))}
  return(invisible())
}
```

I want to call this function on a huge matrix, for example, `outer(1:100,1:100,Vectorize(bar))`. When doing so, I get the printing that I desire, but I also get an output of a huge array of NULL values. How can I adapt this code to get rid of the huge array of NULLs and not lose the printing that I want?

Comment: `NULL` is not nothing. In R, nothing returns nothing.

Comment: @HongOoi But isn't it impossible to write a function that truly returns nothing in R? If you don't use ```return```, then R will use your final line as the return value.

Comment: exactly.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens as you are invoking a side effect within bar() and then jumping up to the top level. The function bar() completes the side effect (printing) then returns the last value in the final command to the top level.

This arrangement returns a single NULL regardless of the sizes of a and b. As in...

```
a <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3,ncol=3)
b <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)

foo <- function(a,b) {
                      exists("a")
                      exists("b")
                     }

bar <- function(a,b) {
                      if(foo(a,b)) {print(c(a,b))}
                      NULL  # or equivalently: return()
                     }

x <- bar(a,b)  # x will be a single NULL
```

Alternatively, you could simply do whatever it is in bar() that you want done, return a and b appropriately and then print outside the function using the returned values. In most cases, this would likely be a better idea. Also the "<<-" operator can be used helpfully here, though global vars have their own issues apart from the side effect here.